# Creation time of scp'd file

Tags: python, linux, shell, unix

Is there a way to get the creation time of an `scp'ed file. For example --

```
>>> item_last_updated = time.ctime(os.path.getmtime('files.txt'))

Davids-iMac:QFS david$ ./ff.py 
>>> #1 Grabbing RawFiles...
files.txt                        100%  146MB 145.7MB/s   00:01    
>>> #2 Updating Data...
>>>>> Thu Oct  8 19:20:30 2015
Davids-iMac:QFS david$ ./ff.py 
>>> #1 Grabbing RawFiles...
files.txt                        100%  146MB 145.7MB/s   00:01    
>>> #2 Updating Data...
>>>>> Thu Oct  8 19:20:34 2015
```

I want it such that the two timestamps are the same. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use: `scp -p`, which preserves file modification time:

> -p
>
> > Preserves modification times, access times, and modes from the original file.